# Enabling PHP7 Opcache

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, opcache

I recently upgraded to PHP 7.

I placed this in /etc/php.d/opcache.ini

```
opcache.file_cache = /var/www/html/.opcache
opcache.file_cache_only = 1
```

and created the directory (as root)

When I visit the site there is nothing created in the .opcache folder

a `phpinfo();` reflects the changes I made in opcache.ini

How can I get PHP 7 Opcache working at optimal performance with WordPress?

*update*
The problem was witch folder permissions. 'Ale sure the Apache can write to it.

What are the optimal settings for it? Security and speed wise?

Comment: I would start by checking the owners/groups/permissions on that folder to make sure your web server can write to it.

Comment: @cmorrissey thanks! What are the recommended settings for it speed and security wise? I read about a webshell exploit, has this been patched or do I need to do something to avoid it?

Comment: Why file cache? This sucks. RAM would be much better.

Comment: If you want to use "file caching", but where the files actually exist in RAM, set the file_cache to `/dev/shm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by making sure apache get write to the folders I created. Once that was done restarting httpd made it work.